# .NET: How to change the value in a DataTable

Tags: data-binding, gridview, ado.net, schema, oledb

In ADO.NET i'm using **[GetSchemaTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdatareader.getschematable.aspx)** to return the schema table for a results set.

```
DataTable schema = rdr.GetSchemaTable();
gridSchema.DataSource = schema;
gridSchema.DataBind();
```

Unfortunatly the **"ProviderType"** value is displaying as an integer, rather than the [OleDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype.aspx) enumeration value that it is:

```
ProviderType     Desired Display Value
============     =====================
129              Char
3                Integer
129              Char
129              Char
3                Integer
3                Integer
129              Char
135              DBTimeStamp
129              Char
129              Char
...
```

All these integers are the the enumeration values for the [OleDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype.aspx) enumeration:

```
public enum OleDbType
{
    Empty = 0,
    SmallInt = 2,
    Integer = 3,
    Single = 4,
    Double = 5,
    Currency = 6,
    Date = 7,
    BSTR = 8,
    IDispatch = 9,
    Error = 10,
    Boolean = 11,
    Variant = 12,
    IUnknown = 13,
    Decimal = 14,
    TinyInt = 16,
    UnsignedTinyInt = 17,
    UnsignedSmallInt = 18,
    UnsignedInt = 19,
    BigInt = 20,
    UnsignedBigInt = 21,
    Filetime = 64,
    Guid = 72,
    Binary = 128,
    Char = 129,
    WChar = 130,
    Numeric = 131,
    DBDate = 133,
    DBTime = 134,
    DBTimeStamp = 135,
    PropVariant = 138,
    VarNumeric = 139,
    VarChar = 200,
    LongVarChar = 201,
    VarWChar = 202,
    LongVarWChar = 203,
    VarBinary = 204,
    LongVarBinary = 205,
}
```

i want to display the data type as something human readable, rather than an integer.

---

i've tried looping through the schema DataTable and modify the values inside the DataTable:

```
DataTable schema = rdr.GetSchemaTable();

//Change providerType column to be readable
foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
{
   OleDbType t = (OleDbType)row["ProviderType"];
   row["ProviderType"] = t.ToString();
}

gridSchema.DataSource = schema;
gridSchema.DataBind();
```

But that throws an exception:

```
Column 'ProviderType' is read only.
```

i even looked at the GridView's [**RowDataBound**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event, thinking i could change the value as it is rendered:

```
protected void gridSchema_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   //todo: magic
   //e.Row["ProviderType"]
}
```

But it doesn't look like you can play with rendered values.

Can anyone suggest a nice way to much with the value of the **ProviderType** column so that it is human readable when i display it to humans?

---

### Update

The workaround i'm using right now is tack an extra column on the end:

```
DataTable schema = rdr.GetSchemaTable();

schema.Columns.Add("OleDbDataType", typeof(String));
schema.Columns.Add("CLRDataType", typeof(String));
foreach (DataRow row in schema.Rows)
{
   //Show the actual provider type
   OleDbType t = (OleDbType)row["ProviderType"];
   row["OleDbDataType"] = t.ToString();

   //Show the corresponding CLR type while we're doing a hack
   row["CLRDataType"] = row["DataType"].ToString();
}

gridSchema.DataSource = schema;
gridSchema.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be completely off here, but can't you just set the ReadOnly property of the column to false? Like:

```
schema.Columns["ProviderType"].ReadOnly = false;
```

Afterwards you might get a columntype problem as you're trying to put a string value into a integer column. But this should get you into the right direction.

**edit:**

Solving the columntype issue:

```
DataTable newTable = schema.Clone();
newTable.Columns["ProviderType"].DataType = typeof(string);

foreach (DataRow dr in schema.Rows)
{
    DataRow newRow = newTable.NewRow();
    // fill newRow with correct data and newly formatted providertype

    newTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

Comment: i was hoping that the datarow's array values are probably objects, i could just stuff a different kind of object in there.

Comment: You're right: it failed. "FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: I added a small piece of code which should help you solve the columntype problem.

Comment: Looks like the answer is "you cannot change values in a `DataTable`". As a workaround you `Clone`d the table.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could create an object with all the fields from the datatable, pass all the data into your object and modify it or create a read only field that returns the string acording to the integer given.

GridView and other also accept object arrays as datasources so it is automatic.